# In Rails, how to convert time zone into an integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have time and time zone, what I need is I just want to convert like this *Wed, 11 Dec 2019 19:00:00 +0530* and then I need to convert like this *1576071000*.

So for I tried like this

```
time = "19"
hour = "00"
time_zone = "IST"

e = DateTime.now.change({hour: time, minute: hour})
```

I get the exact output, but I need to convert with timezone. that means something like this

```
DateTime.now.change({hour: time, minute: hour}).time_zone('IST')
```

Comment: You don't want a DateTime you want a [`TimeWithZone`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) try this instead `Time.zone.now.change({hour: time, minute: hour}).in_time_zone('IST')`

Comment: ArgumentError (Invalid Timezone: IST) its throwing this error

Comment: you have to use timezone known to the server. You can see the available list using `timedatectl list-timezones` (if you are on Linux)

Comment: Okay it is not listed as `IST` but rather `"Chennai"` so use `Time.zone.now.change({hour: time, minute: hour}).in_time_zone('Chennai')` or `Time.zone.now.change({hour: time, minute: hour, offset: "+05:30"})`

Comment: after figuring out your timezone, use `to_i` to get integer number of seconds since the Epoch (January 1, 1970 00:00 UTC).

Answer (score 1):

credit to @engineersmnky

```
hour = 19
minute = 0
time_zone = 'Chennai'

e = Time.zone.now.change({hour: hour, minute: minute}).in_time_zone(time_zone).to_i
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it to UTC:

```
DateTime.now.change({hour: time, minute: hour}).time_zone('IST').utc
```

Or if you are in Rails 4 or above you can use in_time_zone:

```
DateTime.now.change({hour: time, minute: hour}).in_time_zone('IST').utc
```

Comment: getting this error (undefined method `time_zone' for Wed, 11 Dec 2019 19:00:00 +0530:DateTime)